# sql query to get the unique column value for duplicate rows as a separate column

Tags: mysql, join

```
lets get to the situation quickly,
```

so i have a table which contains values as

| id | f_name | l_name | phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | rohan | mehra | 9090909090 |
| 2 | yusuf | yohana | 1010101010 |
| 3 | rohan | mehra | 9090909090 |
| 4 | yusuf | yohana | 1010101010 |

so if yu observe, there are duplicates which i want to extract.
what i exactly want is to create a new table with same columns
and contains values :-

| id | f_name | l_name | phone | secondary_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | rohan | mehra | 9090909090 | 3 |
| 2 | yusuf | yohana | 1010101010 | 4 |

can you help me obtain this.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a third , fourth  a n-th id or is limited to only secondary_id ? And what do you consider unique records ?

Comment: limited to secondary for now.
the one in the 2nd table can be said as unique records.
am i clear?

Comment: Once the new table is created what happens to the old table? If deleted what's the point of capturing the secondary id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a self-join, including the unique columns in the join criteria:

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t1.f_name, t1.l_name, t1.phone, t2.id AS secondary_id
FROM mytable t1
INNER JOIN mytable t2 ON t2.id > t1.id
  AND t1.f_name = t2.f_name
  AND t1.l_name = t2.l_name
  AND t1.phone = t2.phone
```